# Coding a bot for github

Tags: google-hangouts

Hi is it possible or already exist - github chat bot.

I would really like to have one place to follow and discuss github issues.

Can this be done using a chat bot?

Answer (score 0):

Github Bot already exists:

[image]

You just need to go to https://chat.google.com and start a conversation with Github bot or include the bot in a room by mention @github.

Hope it's clear!

Comment: Ahh, I see - they actually can :-|

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a very old post. I was trying to use Github Bot. However it asks me to authorize hangoutschatbot-dev-on-github.
A quick search points to a similar name here - https://github.com/hangoutschatbot-dev-on-github

Just want to be sure that the bot is provided by google and its safe for me to Authorize it.

Comment: I actually never got to use that bot. Just tried it now, allowing it to access my account and you are right it does not look like Google, so I revoked it again. If you find any official bots let mw know.

Comment: FYI, revoking is here: https://github.com/settings/applications

Comment: I believe that the only bot available in Google Chat is the official one: https://support.google.com/chat/answer/9632291?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Actually, when you try to find a bot and you search "github", there is just one result and it says "GitHub bot by Google". So I guess the answer it's still right, you just need to search it on Google Chat. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, so I was trying to use the Github Bot by Google'. The only concerning thing is why is it asking to provide authorization for hangoutschatbot-dev-on-github ?